# CircleCI AWSCLI SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, python-2.7, aws-cli, circleci

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project where AWSCLI is used.
Recently, When I push my code to Staging, it tries to import  newkeys, PrivateKey, PublicKey from rsa.key and throws an error.

The error message is as follows:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rsa/key.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

[Error message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECmFH.png)

My circleci/config.yml file is as follows:

```
orbs:
   aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@7.0.0

version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/mfds
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.3.4-node
      environment:
        RAILS_ENV: citest
        LANG: C.UTF-8
      - image: snowhork/mysql_jp:5.7
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
          MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
          MYSQL_USER: user
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"

  steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
      key: gemfiles-{{ checksum "mfds/Gemfile.lock" }}

  # Bundle install dependencies
  - run: cd mfds/ && bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  # Store bundle cache
  - save_cache:
      key: gemfiles-{{ checksum "mfds/Gemfile.lock" }}
      paths:
        - /home/circleci/mfds/mfds/vendor/bundle

  - run:
      name: Wait for db
      command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:3306 -timeout 1m

  # Database setup
  - run:
      name: db setting
      command: |
        cd mfds
        bundle exec rake db:create
        bundle exec rake db:ridgepole:apply[citest]

  - run:
      name: rspec
      command: |
        cd mfds
        bundle exec rspec

  staging_deploy:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
        name: asset compile
        command: |
          cd mfds
          npm install
          ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --optimize-minimize

     - run:
      name: gem install
      command: |
        gem install aws-sdk-ecs
        pip install futures
        pip install --upgrade awscli

    - run:
      name: push image
      command: |
        export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$XX_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$XX_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        bin/deployv2/docker-push staging

    - run:
      name: update service
      command: |
        export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$XX_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$XX_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        bin/deployv2/update-task staging
   ....
```

I don't understand how to resolve this problem.

Comment: since you are already using orbs at the top, why are you not utilizing the orbs to push the images to ecr repository?